# Camel Blueprint - Gave up waiting for Service exception

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I have a bunch of unit tests that test some routing/camel implementation in Blueprint. These test run absolutely fine 95% of the time however every so often (1 in 20 or so) I get a Camel Runtime exception:

I am running the latest version of Fabric8 with Camel 2.12

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:240)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.createCamelContext(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:304)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:247)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:217)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

Tests in error: 
  SystemStatusRouteBuilderTest>CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp:133->CamelTestSupport.setUp:217->CamelTestSupport.doSetUp:247->CamelBlueprintTestSupport.createCamelContext:304 » Runtime
```

I've triple checked all namespaces in the blueprint file, the pom is packaged as a bundle, the blueprint file is located in the expected location: src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml, and I have the camel maven plugin specified as so:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
   <configuration>
      <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Its very difficult to debug due to its intermittent nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with CamelBlueprintTestSupport.

See comment from Claus here - http://fusesource.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=4695

> Yeah I have seen this from time to time as well. You can run the tests 100 times, and it may fail a few times etc. Not sure what happens, if its pojosr or blueprint etc. Though OSGi and Blueprint has a really complicated startup model where all is async, and kinda waiting for each other. And that is dead hard to test throughly.
>
> You can try setting the surefire plugin to fork the jvm per test. Then its a full fresh JVM on each test. This may fix this, in case there is some "left over" when running all the test in the same JVM.

I have experienced this issue myself as well

Comment: Can confirm I have also experienced this.

Comment: Hi Matt, I came across the above articles as well but was hoping to find something a bit more concrete than the CamelBlueprintTestSupport is just a bit flaky ;) Having spoke to a few ppl though, this does seem to be the case so I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: We found a glitch around the osgi config admin, and a race condition with blueprint - which has been fixed by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7469

Answer (score 3):

I came accross the same the issue (inside a JUnit test) and finally found the reason.
When enabling the full Camel traces, I could see the following message:

"Bundle **** is waiting for dependencies [(&(component=ldap)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver)), (&(component=sql)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))] "

This lead me to add the explicit (test) dependency in my pom, ie:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
  <version>${camel-version}</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

NB: to do for *all* components (jaxb, ldap, sql, cache, etc...) you used in your Camel routes !

This made my error message ("Gave up waiting for Service exception") disappear :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @TacheDeChoco.
I'm facing exactly the same issue with the `camel-sql` component. I defined the `<scope>test</scope>` as you suggested but no success.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue in my project. The root cause is usually the dependency. 
Steps you can try to find the root cause:

1) Remove your project dependencies and just use camel-test-blueprint to run a basic scenario from: http://camel.apache.org/blueprint-testing.html

2) It should work fine ideally :). Now slowly start adding your project dependencies one by one and test your actual scenario (not the one i mentioned above). At one point of time, it would break. If it breaks, you have to avoid using that dependency. If you can't, find another way to run your test i.e. using separate project for test etc...

If you debug the CamelBlueprintTestSupport, you will get yourself lost in it. As  Matthew mentioned, it is difficult to debug async flow. Try my steps and believe me it would work. I did the same.

Answer (score 1):

The history and background of camel-test-blueprint issues can be found here: http://ggrzybek.blogspot.com/2015/12/camel-blueprint-test-support.html

Fixes that improved reliability of these tests are:

- [CAMEL-8948](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8948)
- [CAMEL-7469](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7469)

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same problem with camel 2.16.0 and a new project created using camel-archetype-blueprint.

But I hadn't occasional failures, **mvn camel:run** failed every time I run it.

Changing camel version to 2.14.0 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Apache Camel 2.19.1. The way I solved the problem was changing the archetypes version to 2.18 instead of 2.19 in

*archetypes/camel-archetype-blueprint/pom.xml*

See also [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10602) page

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same exception when there was no camelContext definition in Blueprint descriptor, only beans. I mistakenly believed that no context definition was required while running tests, so it has just not been started.