# How to solve bundle is waiting for namespace handlers [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy] and related issues?

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, jbossfuse, karaf, blueprint

Which bundle do I need for the namespace handler for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy? I need it to configure a ws policy in my [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) component.

My Implementation is a [blueprint](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprint.html) and I am running on [RedHat Fuse 6.3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/6.3/). I know that the error `bundle is waiting for namespace handlers` often means, that you missed a dependency in your instance, but I can't find which bundle is missing here.

I have the following cxf features installed:

```
JBossFuse:admin@s42http1> features:list | grep cxf
[uninstalled] [2.1.0.redhat-630343  ] switchyard-camel-cxf                          switchyard-2.1.0.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [2.1.0.redhat-630343  ] switchyard-quickstart-camel-cxf-binding       switchyard-2.1.0.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-specs                                     cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-jaxb                                      cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-abdera                                    cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [2.1.7                ] wss4j                                         cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-core                                      cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-commands                                  cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-wsdl                                      cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-ws-policy                                 cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-ws-addr                                   cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-ws-rm                                     cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-ws-mex                                    cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-ws-security                               cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rt-security                               cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rt-security-saml                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-http-client                               cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-http                                      cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-http-jetty                                cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-http-async                                cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-http-netty-client                         cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-http-netty-server                         cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-bindings-soap                             cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-jaxws                                     cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-jaxrs                                     cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rs-security-xml                           cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rs-security-sso-saml                      cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rs-security-cors                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rs-security-oauth                         cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rs-security-jose                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rs-security-oauth2                        cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-rs-description-swagger2                   cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-databinding-aegis                         cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-databinding-jibx                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-databinding-jaxb                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-databinding-xmlbeans                      cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-features-clustering                       cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-features-logging                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-features-throttling                       cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-features-metrics                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-bindings-corba                            cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-bindings-coloc                            cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-bindings-object                           cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-transports-local                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-transports-jms                            cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-transports-udp                            cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-transports-websocket-client               cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-transports-websocket-server               cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-javascript                                cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-frontend-javascript                       cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-xjc-runtime                               cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-tools                                     cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf                                           cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-sts                                       cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-wsn-api                                   cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-wsn                                       cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-ws-discovery-api                          cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-ws-discovery                              cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-bean-validation-core                      cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-bean-validation                           cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-management-web                            cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [3.1.5.redhat-630343  ] cxf-jaxrs-cdi                                 cxf-3.1.5.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [1.2.0.redhat-630343  ] fabric-cxf                                    fabric-1.2.0.redhat-630343
[uninstalled] [1.2.0.redhat-630343  ] fabric-cxf-registry                           fabric-1.2.0.redhat-630343
[installed  ] [2.17.0.redhat-630343 ] camel-cxf                                     camel-2.17.0.redhat-630343
```

Maybe somebody can give a hint, how you can figure out the missing dependency. A related question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721820/bundle-is-waiting-for-namespace-handlers-http-camel-apache-org-schema-bluepri/52929618#52929618).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by changing the namespaces for the web service policy. Previously we had the following namespaces

**A**:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
            xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
```

and then we switched to

**B**:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" 
            xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
```

**A** is using the [Web Service Policy 1.2](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/) and **B** is using the [Web Service Policy 1.5](https://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy/). The [CXF Documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-to-define-policies.html) sais, that you should use Web Service Policy 1.5.

> **Web Services Policy 1.5** - Attachment standard describes all possible alternatives.

So it seems to have been a problem with the version.