# Why is Aries Blueprint not registering a namespace handler for camel-cxf and camel-blueprint?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

Camel 2.23.1Karaf 4.2.4

- Aries Blueprint (for the outer container that registers everything)
- Camel Blueprint (for Camel routes)
- Camel CXF (for rsServer)
- CXF Core (for access to the CXF bus property)

XML Namespaces

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
           xmlns:cxfcore="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint-2.23.1.xsd
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf-2.23.1-blueprint.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd"
```

Error blueprint namespace handlers:

```
Status: GracePeriod
Declarative Services
Blueprint
12.04.19, 09:00
Missing dependencies:
(&(objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)(osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf)) (&(objectClass=org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler)(osgi.service.blueprint.namespace=http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint))
```

In summary, the following are not registered by Aries Blueprint:

- http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint
- http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf

> The blueprint runtime does not parse the blueprint xml until NamespaceHandler services can be found for every custom namespace that is used in the bundle. Unless NamespaceHandler services can be found for every custom namespace, the blueprint container is unable to process the bundle. This result can mean that the blueprint container waits indefinitely if no NamespaceHandler exists.
>    https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_blueprint_namespace_handler.html

I know Aries Blueprint is running and registering some namespaces because of these karaf.log entries:

```
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/bindings/soap
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/simple
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/policy
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs-client
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/beans
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/parameterized-types
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing
Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration
```

Karaf: as you can see, My Awesome Application is stuck (likely in a loop)

```
 ID │ State       │ Lvl │ Version │ Name
────┼─────────────┼─────┼─────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 23 │ Active      │  80 │ 4.2.4   │ Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
 45 │ GracePeriod │  80 │ 1.0.0   │ My Awesome Application
 46 │ Active      │  80 │ 0.0.0   │ features.xml
 51 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.9.7   │ Jackson-JAXRS-base
 52 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.9.7   │ Jackson-JAXRS-JSON
 71 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1  │ camel-blueprint
 72 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.23.1  │ camel-commands-core
 73 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1  │ camel-core
 74 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1  │ camel-cxf
 75 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1  │ camel-cxf-transport
 76 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1  │ camel-http-common
 77 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1  │ camel-spring
 78 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.23.1  │ camel-karaf-commands
102 │ Active      │  80 │ 1.1.1   │ geronimo-jms_1.1_spec
112 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.0.19  │ Apache MINA Core
144 │ Active      │  80 │ 4.12.0  │ Apache XBean OSGI Bundle Utilities
145 │ Active      │  80 │ 4.12.0  │ Apache XBean :: Classpath Resource Finder
```

Another intermittent error showed up regarding the HttpServer.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.service.http.HttpService not found by org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http
```

My first inkling would be that this is required for the namespace handlers to validate the namespaces, but removing karaf in its entirety and reinstalling everything does not always yield this error. In fact, I get:

```
2019-04-12T09:45:31,438 | DEBUG | paxweb-config-1-thread-1 | pax-web-runtime                  | 181 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 7.2.8 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.osgi.service.http.HttpService, org.ops4j.pax.web.service.WebContainer] - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime
```

bundle:services -p org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint

```
camel-blueprint (71) provides:
------------------------------
objectClass = [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler]
osgi.service.blueprint.namespace = [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint, http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder]
service.bundleid = 71
service.id = 198
service.scope = bundle
----
objectClass = [org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer]
osgi.blueprint.container.symbolicname = org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
osgi.blueprint.container.version = 2.23.1
service.bundleid = 71
service.id = 199
service.scope = singleton
----
objectClass = [org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.info.InfoProvider]
service.bundleid = 71
service.id = 200
service.scope = singleton
```

list -t 0 -l

```
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 0
 ID │ State       │ Lvl │ Version            │ Location
────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  0 │ Active      │   0 │ 5.6.12             │ System Bundle
  1 │ Resolved    │   1 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.extension/4.2.4
  2 │ Active      │   5 │ 1.2.2              │ mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.metatype/1.2.2
  3 │ Active      │   5 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.services/org.apache.karaf.services.eventadmin/4.2.4
  4 │ Active      │   5 │ 2.6.1              │ mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-aether/2.6.1
  5 │ Active      │   8 │ 1.17.1             │ mvn:org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.17.1
  6 │ Active      │   8 │ 1.10.1             │ mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.10.1
  7 │ Active      │   8 │ 1.10.1             │ mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2/1.10.1
  8 │ Active      │   9 │ 1.0.2              │ mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.coordinator/1.0.2
  9 │ Active      │  10 │ 1.9.14             │ mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.configadmin/1.9.14
 10 │ Active      │  11 │ 3.6.4              │ mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.fileinstall/3.6.4
 11 │ Active      │  15 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.2.4
 12 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.9.0              │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.activation-api-1.1/2.9.0
 13 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.1.5              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.api/1.1.5
 14 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.1.8              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.core/1.1.8
 15 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.2.0              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.whiteboard/1.2.0
 16 │ Active      │  20 │ 1.1.3              │ mvn:org.apache.aries/org.apache.aries.util/1.1.3
 17 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.bundle/org.apache.karaf.bundle.core/4.2.4
 18 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.config/org.apache.karaf.config.core/4.2.4
 19 │ Active      │  26 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.features/4.2.4
 20 │ Active      │  24 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar/4.2.4
 21 │ Active      │  24 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.wrap/4.2.4
 22 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.diagnostic/org.apache.karaf.diagnostic.core/4.2.4
 23 │ Active      │  80 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf/org.apache.karaf.event/4.2.4
 24 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.command/4.2.4
 25 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.instance/org.apache.karaf.instance.core/4.2.4
 26 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.command/4.2.4
 27 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.config/4.2.4
 28 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules/4.2.4
 29 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.kar/org.apache.karaf.kar.core/4.2.4
 30 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.log/org.apache.karaf.log.core/4.2.4
 31 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.management/org.apache.karaf.management.server/4.2.4
 32 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.package/org.apache.karaf.package.core/4.2.4
 33 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.service/org.apache.karaf.service.core/4.2.4
 34 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.commands/4.2.4
 35 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.core/4.2.4
 36 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh/4.2.4
 37 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.system/org.apache.karaf.system.core/4.2.4
 38 │ Active      │  30 │ 0.3.11.1           │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.not-yet-commons-ssl/0.3.11_1
 39 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.7.0              │ mvn:org.apache.sshd/sshd-core/1.7.0
 40 │ Active      │  30 │ 3.10.0             │ mvn:org.jline/jline-builtins/3.10.0
 41 │ Active      │  30 │ 3.10.0             │ mvn:org.jline/jline-reader/3.10.0
 42 │ Active      │  30 │ 3.10.0             │ mvn:org.jline/jline-terminal/3.10.0
 43 │ Resolved    │  30 │ 3.10.0             │ mvn:org.jline/jline-terminal-jansi/3.10.0
 44 │ Active      │   5 │ 2.6.1              │ mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-wrap/2.6.1/jar/uber
 45 │ Active      │  80 │ 0.0.0              │ feature:file:/usr/local/karaf/apache-karaf-4.2.4/deploy/features.xml
 46 │ GracePeriod │  90 │ 1.0.0              │ file:/usr/local/karaf/apache-karaf-4.2.4/deploy/my-awesome-application-1.0.0.jar
 47 │ Active      │  35 │ 2.9.7              │ mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.7
 48 │ Active      │  35 │ 2.9.7              │ mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.7
 49 │ Active      │  35 │ 2.9.7              │ mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7
 50 │ Active      │  35 │ 2.9.7              │ mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.9.7
 51 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.9.7              │ wrap:mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/...
 52 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.9.7              │ wrap:mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/...
 53 │ Active      │  35 │ 2.9.7              │ mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.9.7
 54 │ Active      │  20 │ 5.0.3              │ mvn:com.fasterxml.woodstox/woodstox-core/5.0.3
 55 │ Active      │  25 │ 20.0.0             │ mvn:com.google.guava/guava/20.0
 56 │ Active      │  25 │ 3.2.6              │ mvn:io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core/3.2.6
 57 │ Active      │  10 │ 1.3                │ mvn:javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3
 58 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.4.7              │ mvn:javax.mail/mail/1.4.7
 59 │ Active      │  30 │ 3.1.0              │ mvn:javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0
 60 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.1                │ mvn:javax.websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.1
 61 │ Active      │  25 │ 2.9.4              │ mvn:joda-time/joda-time/2.9.4
 62 │ Active      │  40 │ 2.10.5             │ mvn:net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.5
 63 │ Active      │  20 │ 1.0.1              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.api/1.0.1
 64 │ Active      │  20 │ 1.3.1              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.cm/1.3.1
 65 │ Active      │  20 │ 1.10.1             │ mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core/1.10.1
 66 │ Resolved    │  20 │ 1.0.0              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.blueprint/org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.compatibility/1.0.0
 67 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.2.0              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.blueprint.api/1.2.0
 68 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.2.0              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.jmx/org.apache.aries.jmx.blueprint.core/1.2.0
 69 │ Active      │  20 │ 1.1.4              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.proxy/org.apache.aries.proxy/1.1.4
 70 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.2.0              │ mvn:org.apache.aries.spifly/org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle/1.2
 71 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1             │ mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-blueprint/2.23.1
 72 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.23.1             │ mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-commands-core/2.23.1
 73 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1             │ mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.23.1
 74 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1             │ mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-cxf/2.23.1
 75 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1             │ mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-cxf-transport/2.23.1
 76 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1             │ mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-http-common/2.23.1
 77 │ Active      │  50 │ 2.23.1             │ mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-spring/2.23.1
 78 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.23.1             │ mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/camel-karaf-commands/2.23.1
 79 │ Active      │  25 │ 1.11.0             │ mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11
 80 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.2.7
 81 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/3.2.7
 82 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-xml/3.2.7
 83 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-aegis/3.2.7
 84 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.2.7
 85 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-features-logging/3.2.7
 86 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/3.2.7
 87 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/3.2.7
 88 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/3.2.7
 89 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-management/3.2.7
 90 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-client/3.2.7
 91 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers/3.2.7
 92 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-search/3.2.7
 93 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-json-basic/3.2.7
 94 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-service-description/3.2.7
 95 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/3.2.7
 96 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty/3.2.7
 97 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-ws-policy/3.2.7
 98 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-wsdl/3.2.7
 99 │ Active      │  40 │ 3.2.7              │ mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/cxf-karaf-commands/3.2.7
100 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.1.16             │ mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr/2.1.16
101 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.1                │ mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jaspic_1.0_spec/1.1
102 │ Active      │  80 │ 1.1.1              │ mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1
103 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.1.1              │ mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1
104 │ Active      │   9 │ 1.1                │ mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-osgi-registry/1.1
105 │ Active      │  10 │ 1.1.3              │ mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec/1.1.3
106 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.bundle/org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate/4.2.4
107 │ Active      │  24 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.blueprint/4.2.4
108 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.http/org.apache.karaf.http.core/4.2.4
109 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.jaas.blueprint/org.apache.karaf.jaas.blueprint.config/4.2.4
110 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.scr/org.apache.karaf.scr.management/4.2.4
111 │ Active      │  30 │ 4.2.4              │ mvn:org.apache.karaf.scr/org.apache.karaf.scr.state/4.2.4
112 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.0.19             │ mvn:org.apache.mina/mina-core/2.0.19
113 │ Active      │  30 │ 3.1.1              │ mvn:org.apache.neethi/neethi/3.1.1
114 │ Active      │  25 │ 2.1.2              │ mvn:org.apache.santuario/xmlsec/2.1.2
115 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.0.0.6            │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance/1.0_6
116 │ Active      │  30 │ 5.2.0.4            │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.bcel/5.2_4
117 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.2.13.1           │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.fastinfoset/1.2.13_1
118 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.9.2.1            │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jasypt/1.9.2_1
119 │ Active      │  20 │ 2.2.11.1           │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl/2.2.11_1
120 │ Active      │  20 │ 2.2.11.1           │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-xjc/2.2.11_1
121 │ Active      │  25 │ 3.3.0.2            │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml/3.3.0_2
122 │ Active      │  25 │ 1.3.23.2           │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.saaj-impl/1.3.23_2
123 │ Active      │  30 │ 5.1.5.RELEASE_1    │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop/5.1.5.RELEASE_1
124 │ Active      │  30 │ 5.1.5.RELEASE_1    │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans/5.1.5.RELEASE_1
125 │ Active      │  30 │ 5.1.5.RELEASE_1    │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context/5.1.5.RELEASE_1
126 │ Active      │  30 │ 5.1.5.RELEASE_1    │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support/5.1.5.RELEASE_1
127 │ Active      │  30 │ 5.1.5.RELEASE_1    │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core/5.1.5.RELEASE_1
128 │ Active      │  30 │ 5.1.5.RELEASE_1    │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-expression/5.1.5.RELEASE_1
129 │ Active      │  30 │ 5.1.5.RELEASE_1    │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx/5.1.5.RELEASE_1
130 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.6.3.1            │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.wsdl4j/1.6.3_1
131 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.7.2.3            │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xalan/2.7.2_3
132 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.12.0.1           │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xerces/2.12.0_1
133 │ Active      │  25 │ 1.2.0.5            │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver/1.2_5
134 │ Active      │  10 │ 2.9.1              │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxrs-api-2.1/2.9.1
135 │ Active      │  10 │ 2.9.0              │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxws-api-2.2/2.9.0
136 │ Active      │  10 │ 2.9.0              │ mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.saaj-api-1.3/2.9.0
137 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.2.3              │ mvn:org.apache.ws.xmlschema/xmlschema-core/2.2.3
138 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.2.2              │ mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-bindings/2.2.2
139 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.2.2              │ mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-policy/2.2.2
140 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.2.2              │ mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-common/2.2.2
141 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.2.2              │ mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-dom/2.2.2
142 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.2.2              │ mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax/2.2.2
143 │ Active      │  30 │ 2.2.2              │ mvn:org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-stax/2.2.2
144 │ Active      │  80 │ 4.12.0             │ mvn:org.apache.xbean/xbean-bundleutils/4.12
145 │ Active      │  80 │ 4.12.0             │ mvn:org.apache.xbean/xbean-finder/4.12
146 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.4.0              │ mvn:org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/1.4.0
147 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client/9.4.12.v20180830
148 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-continuation/9.4.12.v20180830
149 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-deploy/9.4.12.v20180830
150 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http/9.4.12.v20180830
151 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/9.4.12.v20180830
152 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jaas/9.4.12.v20180830
153 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jmx/9.4.12.v20180830
154 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jndi/9.4.12.v20180830
155 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-plus/9.4.12.v20180830
156 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-rewrite/9.4.12.v20180830
157 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-security/9.4.12.v20180830
158 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jaspi/9.4.12.v20180830
159 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.12.v20180830
160 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.12.v20180830
161 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlets/9.4.12.v20180830
162 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util/9.4.12.v20180830
163 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util-ajax/9.4.12.v20180830
164 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-webapp/9.4.12.v20180830
165 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-api/9.4.12.v20180830
166 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-client/9.4.12.v20180830
167 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-common/9.4.12.v20180830
168 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl/9.4.12.v20180830
169 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/9.4.12.v20180830
170 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-server/9.4.12.v20180830
171 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-servlet/9.4.12.v20180830
172 │ Active      │  30 │ 9.4.12.v20180830   │ mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-xml/9.4.12.v20180830
173 │ Active      │  25 │ 1.7.6              │ mvn:org.jvnet.staxex/stax-ex/1.7.6
174 │ Active      │  20 │ 7.1.0              │ mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm/7.1
175 │ Active      │  20 │ 7.1.0              │ mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/7.1
176 │ Active      │  20 │ 7.1.0              │ mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/7.1
177 │ Active      │  20 │ 7.1.0              │ mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/7.1
178 │ Active      │  20 │ 7.1.0              │ mvn:org.ow2.asm/asm-util/7.1
179 │ Active      │  30 │ 7.2.8              │ mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-api/7.2.8
181 │ Active      │  30 │ 7.2.8              │ mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-runtime/7.2.8
182 │ Active      │  30 │ 7.2.8              │ mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-spi/7.2.8
183 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.0.0.201505202023 │ mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.util.function/1.0.0
184 │ Active      │  30 │ 1.0.0.201505202023 │ mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.util.promise/1.0.0
185 │ Active      │  35 │ 1.23.0             │ mvn:org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.23
186 │ Active      │  20 │ 3.1.4              │ mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4
187 │ Active      │  10 │ 4.4.1              │ mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.4.1
188 │ Active      │  80 │ 1.4.23.Final       │ mvn:io.undertow/undertow-core/1.4.23.Final
189 │ Active      │  80 │ 1.4.23.Final       │ mvn:io.undertow/undertow-servlet/1.4.23.Final
190 │ Active      │  80 │ 1.4.23.Final       │ mvn:io.undertow/undertow-websockets-jsr/1.4.23.Final
191 │ Active      │  80 │ 3.3.8.Final        │ mvn:org.jboss.xnio/xnio-api/3.3.8.Final
192 │ Active      │  80 │ 3.3.8.Final        │ mvn:org.jboss.xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.8.Final
193 │ Active      │  80 │ 7.2.8              │ mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-undertow/7.2.8
```

features.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0 http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.4.0"
          name="my-awesome-application-features">
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/${camel.version}/xml/features</repository>
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/${cxf.version}/xml/features</repository>
    <feature name="my-awesome-application" version="${project.version}" install="auto">
        <feature version="${cxf.version}" dependency="true">cxf</feature>
        <feature version="1.10.2" dependency="true">aries-blueprint</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}" dependency="true">camel</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}" dependency="true">camel-api</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}" dependency="true">camel-base</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}" dependency="true">camel-core</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}" dependency="true">camel-cxf</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}" dependency="true">camel-blueprint</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}" dependency="true">camel-paxlogging</feature>
        <feature version="${camel.version}" dependency="true">camel-stream</feature>
        <bundle start-level="90">file:deploy/my-awesome-application-${project.version}.jar</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

- [Bundle is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721820/bundle-is-waiting-for-namespace-handlers-http-camel-apache-org-schema-bluepri)

Comment: `camel-blueprint` should be the one registering the namespace handler.

Comment: After I installed camel-blueprint, I could check this `bundle:services -p org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint` command and I saw it registers proper `org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler` service

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek Aha! So is Karaf's "first come, first serve" policy causing this to fail? How can I ensure the correct order every time?

Comment: no no - order is not relevant. I started with fresh karaf 4.2.4, then installed camel features using `feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.23.1/xml/features` then `feature:install camel-blueprint`. Please check what `bundle:services -p org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint` gives you

Comment: for this CNFE, please install for example `feature:install pax-http-undertow`

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek  I added output of `bundle:services -p org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint`

Comment: what happens if you restart bundle 45?

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek Nothing. I added the error after running `feature:install pax-http-undertow`.

Comment: Please show me full output of `list -t 0 -l`

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek added `list -t 0 -l` output.

Comment: I'm wondering about ` 45 │ Active      │  80 │ 0.0.0              │ feature:file:/usr/local/karaf/apache-karaf-4.2.4/deploy/features.xml` - this is strange - as if feature was installed as bundle...

Comment: also - if you already have jetty, don't install pax-http-undertow, but pax-http-jetty

Comment: can you share your project on github?

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek Not possible, sorry. However, I did add the contents of features.xml. Karaf recognizes it as a bundle (dropped in the deploy dir).

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek I was able to get rid of the error by altering the generated MANIFEST.MF (maven-bundle-plugin). Instead of embedding everything: `<Embed-Dependency>*`, I embed only what I really need: `<Embed-Dependency>com.jcraft.*` I wish to understand the problem, however. Is it possible to confirm that Karaf was using the wrong name handler—the embedded handler? (Again, because of Karaf's first come, first serve behavior?)

Comment: If you had everything embeded - probably you had embedded also blueprint-core and blueprint-api bundles. So Aries could really not detect the namespace handlers - or the requirement of those handlers from your bundle.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek +1 Great! I would like to confirm this and provide a thorough answer. Your help was invaluable. Aries clearly detected some handlers as shown in the karaf.log. I'd like to confirm which ones. I guess the ones not embedded in my app. Maybe a question is then: was anything using the embedded blueprint-core and blueprint-api bundles? camel?

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek Why should I install `pax-http-jetty`? Anything to do with my intermittent error `Activator start error in bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http`

Comment: yes - if you need org.osgi.service.http, pax-web bundles provides this (pax-web-api bundle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important that the Aries Blueprint (`blueprint-core`) and Aries Blueprint API (`blueprint-api`) are not declared as embedded in the MANIFEST.MF. When using the maven-bundle-plugin, this is equivalent to having a look at the pom.xml

```
<Embed-Dependency>
   *
</Embed-Dependency>
```

A star here would include, for example, the `blueprint-core`, `blueprint-api`, `camel-core`, `blueprint-blueprint`. This could lead to Karaf checking the wrong namespace registry when looking for namespace handlers.

I simply removed the Kleene star * and embedded only non-OSGI packages that I needed. However, if you want a star, then there is also a solution. Because the Embed-Dependency is processed sequentially (top-down), it is possible to exclude dependencies before the star like this:

```
<Embed-Dependency>
   !org.apache.aries.blueprint-core,
   !org.apache.aries.blueprint-api,
   *
</Embed-Dependency>
```

The star will not include pre-negated packages.

Also, it could be that two Karaf features declared in the `features.xml` start multiple instances of CXF, i.e. feature `camel-cxf` and `feature cxf`, which might lead to only one of them registering with the Blueprint Namespace Handler.